# Similiarity search with mongodb for string (not text)

Tags: mongodb

I want to query strings with random characters in DB that are not always equal. For example,

```
fc3ff81fe007c001ffbff007e201e001e001fdc1fe01fe03bfcf8007e007f807
```

and

```
fc3ff81fe007c001ffbff007e201e001e001fdc1fe01fe03bfcf8007e007f910
```

These strings are almost the same, but three characters at the end are different, which means they are 95,3125% similiar. How to pass this value to MongoDB to find strings that are 95% or more similiar to passed? I tried text indexes but they seem to work with regular text, not strings.

Comment: I don't think text similarity is some regular feature for any database. Likely you will need to use some application code / analytics engine to achieve that

Comment: Are all the strings the same length?  If not, how do you want calculate percentage similarity?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yes, they are the same length. By calculating diffs (char position equals to same char in the same position). If one string is shorter, every condition becomes false, because any char is not equal to nothing.

Comment: Calculating percentage similarity for same length strings isn't too difficult. For different length strings, should the longest string be used as the denominator? For example, if the string in the collection is half the length of the comparison string, and all characters present match, what is the percentage? ... and vice versa?  Both 50%?

Comment: @rickhg12hs The challenge is to do that inside mongodb, for now I just querying all documents inside NodeJS array (luckily there is just few thousands, not millions) and then comparing them.

Comment: Do you want a MongoDB query that will produce the percent similarity of equal length strings?

Comment: ... and to simplify argument processing, will each document have a hex string defined?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I'm not sure what you mean, but I want it as simple as text index which has "score"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not exactly sure what you are looking for, but here's one way to compare two strings of equal length and calculate the percentage of characters that agree in like positions.  Some care was taken to account for empty and non-existent strings, although you may want to change/delete it depending on the results you are seeking.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { // Is the field "hexStr" present and a string?
    "$set": {
      "hexStr": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$and": [
              { "hexStr": { "$type": 2 } },
              { "$ifNull": [ "$hexStr", false ] }
            ]
          },
          "$hexStr",  // It's fine. leave it
          ""          // Something's wrong, set it to an empty string for convenience
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {  // count the number of equal character positions
    "$set": {
      "eqlCnt": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": { "$range": [ 0, { "$strLenCP": "$hexStr" } ] },
          "initialValue": 0,
          "in": {
            "$sum": [
              "$$value",
              {
                "$cond": [
                  {
                    "$eq": [
                      {
                        "$substrCP": [
                          // comparison str arg
                          "fc3ff81fe007c001ffbff007e201e001e001fdc1fe01fe03bfcf8007e007f807",
                          "$$this",
                          1
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "$substrCP": [
                          // doc str
                          "$hexStr",
                          "$$this",
                          1
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  1,
                  0
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {  // calculate percentage if "hexStr" length > 0, otherwise just 0
    "$set": {
      "percentSim": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$gt": [ { "$strLenCP": "$hexStr" }, 0 ] },
          { "$divide": [ "$eqlCnt", { "$strLenCP": "$hexStr" } ] },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jeq2Ic_jdv4).